# Localization and RTl layout changing tableview works on simulator but not real decive

Tags: ios

I used the localization and RTl layout to change the tableview when i tested on simulator it works good but when I tested on real device it doesn't work. Why is this?

```
(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewRowAction *editAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Edit" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        // show UIActionSheet
        NSLog(@"im pressed the edit");
    }];
    editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath) {
        // flag the row
        NSLog(@"im pressed the delete/");

    }];
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return @[editAction, deleteAction];
}
```

Comment: and the delete and edit button when use the pan gesture on cell it appear on simulator but on real device not also the layout of the table not change to right to left on real device but it works on simulator

Comment: What OS version is your device running on? What's its language set to? Can you show some screenshots?